# Restricted list creation in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list

In SharePoint 2010 is it possible to have an 'almost owner' group where the user can alter membership (except for the owner group and not create groups) and only add certain list types (e.g. those in the list template gallery). If non-owner group management is not possible, is it still possible to restrict what kinds of lists can be created, without the need to turn off features?

i.e. delegate rights to allow someone else to create calendars or documents lists, but not any others

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is part of the new Governance Model in ur ORG :)

It should be possible by creating a new permission level and blocking

- Manage Permissions
- Create Subsites
- Manage Web Site Manage Lists (if want
  to block creation )

Deactivate unused features which will automatically remove the lists types from gallery

Assign this permission level to the non-owner group

**Make Sure to check the cascading effects, coz one permssion can deactive other too :)**

check out : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proficient to answer exactly what you're asking, but I can suggest a work around.

You could add your 'Restricted users' to a group, and create a List Event Receiver. In your ListAdding event, you could check if the user has permission to create this kind of list, and abort with a message if he don't.

I know it's not the optimal solution, but it might be able to do some of what you're asking.